# TTNavigator three20 openURLAction

Tags: iphone, sdk, three20, ttnavigator

I'm new to three20 and trying to find my way through the TTNavigator class.
I try to push to a new view via the URL system.
So I used openURL: animated: method which works just fine, but it's deprecated, and I know that I should use openURLAction instead, but this has no animated: parameter. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The navigator now uses `TTURLAction` and the `applyXXX` method:

```
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:UrlFor(@"foo/bar")] applyAnimated:YES]];
```

This lets it be much more scaleable in that there doesn't have to be a n^2 constructors.  There are many other `applyXXX` methods, check out the docs [here](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/60340d76780ac5ab8a5dc853e3577b1c854eb6e0/src/Three20/TTNavigator.h) and [here](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/5ffc8d0d54cfbbb4b48fd3564c9d9ae5b5ce87b3/src/Three20/TTURLAction.h)